# How can I grab a value from the code of the page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, search, get, fetch

Here is [the source code of the page](https://www.pastiebin.com/5cfb6678510df).

The line that has the value that I want to grab is at line 194 exactly.

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KlqGgM/3), but it returned `undefined` and I can't fix it
by `var test = getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)"; console.log(test[1]);`

And this one too, gave me: `undefined`.

If there only was a way to do this:

```
/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/g.exec('getObj("Frm_Logintoken").value =  ?
```

There is a question mark, because I don't know its value, and if the code can replace the question mark with the value of that value from line 194, that would be great.

Not the value is a page generated value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.match(regex)[value_index]` to extract mached values from regx (the values inside parenthesis in regular expression will be extracted).

in your case:

`str.match(/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/)[1]`

here is a working example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/vwoeJL)

Comment: Is there a way to fetch value first? Because if I knew the value it would have been better to use it directly in the automatically login code that i am trying to make.

the value is stored at the page not at my mind

Comment: @minanageh not sure what do you mean. you have a page, you use this regx to extract the value (in this example it will give you 7). how else can you get value? you want to get it without regx?

Comment: @minanageh "Is there a way to fetch value first" i don't get what you mean by "FIRST". get value before what?

Comment: @minanageh also make sure to see the codepen link in answer.

Comment: .

this isn't what extracting means !
how will i type `var string = ‘getObj(“Frm_Logintoken”).value = “7”;’;`
while i need to fetch it first to know it's value ? 
"how else can you get value"  i don't know maybe by grabbing  that line 194 and taking the value from it ? 
"you want to get it without regx?"
i don't know i just want to get it but from the line 194 not a value that's written by me !
"i don't get what you mean by "FIRST". get value before what?"
getting the value before using your code to add it to the code so it results in the correct in page stored value.

Comment: @minanageh man you're not going to put the string value manually, it's the document string. you should get document string somehow (for example with ajax), and store it in a variable like `string`, and use regx.match.

Comment: @minanageh the `var string = ‘getObj(“Frm_Logintoken”).value = “7”;’;` is just for testing purpose. you can change it to whatever you want. did you get it?

Comment: @minanageh it's something like this: `var string = get_contents_of_url('www.google.com'); var found_value = string.match(/getObj\("Frm_Logintoken"\).value = "(.*)";/)[1]`

Comment: "you should get document string somehow (for example with ajax), and store it in a variable "

this is the main purpose of the question this what i am trying tell every one from the begging !!
do you know it's answer ? or should i ask a new question  ? if so  what should it's title be ?

Comment: @minanageh you don't know how to get document from url? you want to get it in javascript?

Comment: "you don't know how to get document from url" no i don't ... is this the solution that i need ? "you want to get it in javascript? "
if it would be better then yes

Comment: @minanageh aren't you on chat?

Comment: i am in it . where are you ?